# Есть ли класс хранения ресурсов?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer, std

Есть выделенный ресурс(не память), который нужно освободить с помощью своей функции. Мне нужна функциональность std::shared_ptr -- он умеет считать количество копий самого себя + ему в конструктор можно засунуть свою функцию по освобождению. Он заточен под память в куче.
Можно представить мой ресурс, как простой id (unsigned int). После завершения работы с этим id мне его нужно освободить. Совсем не хочется велосипедить и перевыделять этот id в куче (чтобы пихнуть в shared) или писать свой умный указатель -- мне кажется есть стандартные способы реализовать это. Как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте небольшой класс, который будет работать с этим Id. Вам точно нужно уметь его освобождать (деструктор) и уметь загружать (конструктор). И скорее всего нужны какие то базовые функции с ним. И этот класс уже помещаете в `shared_ptr`. Также можно будет использовать и `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Звучит здорово - попробую